# Convertir hora formato 12 hrs a formato 24 hrs (Js)

Tags: javascript

Tomo la información de BD y se muestra en el select con horarios que vienen de formato 12 hrs.
Lo que intento tomar es la hora y convertirla mediante javascript a horario de 24 horas.

Ya logro tomar la hora en el input pero intento convertirlo a 24 horas y pasarlo así al input.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué manera podría hacerse con JS?

Comparto el ejemplo (con info fija en el select).

```
 <center>
  
       <form action="#" method="post">
  
  
  <select  name="time_slot" id="aslots"  > 

    <option>1:00 P.M. To 2:00 P.M</option>
    <option >2:00 P.M. To 3:00 P.M</option>
    <option>03:00 P.M. To 04:00 P.M</option>
    <option>04:00 P.M. To 05:00 P.M</option>
    <option>05:00 P.M. To 06:00 P.M</option>
    <option >05:00 P.M. To 07:00 P.M</option>
    
     </select>
                                                    
                                                    
                                                                                                      <input name="myInput2" id="myInput2" value='' placeholder=""  >
     

 <button type="submit" name="submit" > <?php echo 'Enviar'; ?></button>

</form>


    <script>
    var optCarrera = document.getElementById("aslots")
optCarrera.onchange = function(){

 
}
</script>


<script>
    $(function(){
    $(document).on('change','#aslots',function(){ 
      var value = $(this).val().substring (0,5) ;
   
         if (value = 07:00) {
      var value = '19:00';
       }  else { 
           var value = '00:00';
           
       }
   
   
      $('#myInput2').val(value);
    });
  });
</script>
  
    </center>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-convert-24-hours-format-to-12-hours-in-javascript-ca19dfd7419d#:~:text=Convert%20the%2024%20hours%20format%20time%20to%2012%20hours%20formatted%20time.&text=Now%20in%2Dorder%20to%20convert,12%20on%20the%20current%20time.&text=time%20%3D%2024%2C%20then%2024%25,change%20the%20time%20as%2012. en esta url vi varios ejemplos puedes usar uno que te acomode

Comment: @sysbot Las mismas personas que están detrás de Moment.js [recomiendan ya no utilizarlo](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/).

Answer (score 4):

Convertir a formato 12h

```
var hora24, hora12, pm;

hora24 = hora12 = new Date().getHours();  // captura la hora actual pero pude ser sustituido por una hora antes definida de tipo entero

if (hora24 > 12) {
    hora12 -= (hora24 - 12);
    pm = true; // am = false;
} else {
    pm = false; // am = true;
}
```

Convertir a formato 24h

```
let hora24, hora12, pm;

// cambiar los parametros a la hora obtenida
pm = false
hora12 = 12
    
if (pm) {
    hora24 = hora12 + 12;
} else{
    hora24 = hora12;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes hacer usando la librería de [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) es mas practica para la gestión de fechas y horas en Javascript ya que tiene establecidas funcionalidades que puedes usar, incluyendo lo que necesitas de cambiar la hora de formato 24 a 12.

Usando `moment().format('LT');`

Comment: MomentJS está marcado como [obsoleto y no recomendado](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) por sus propios autores. Evita usarlo y / o recomendarlo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**Cómo convertir el formato de 24 horas a 12 horas en Javascript.**

Se puede obtener el tiempo de esta forma:

```
var dt = new Date();
var hours = dt.getHours(); // da el valor en formato de 24 horas
var minutes = dt.getMinutes() ; 
var finalTime = "Time  - " + hours + ":" + minutes; 
finalTime // final time Time - 22:10
```

Ahora, para convertirlo al formato de 12 horas, puede obtener el valor `%12` de la hora actual, por ejemplo:

Si el tiempo es 13 entonces `13%12 → 1`

tiempo = 23 luego `23%12 →11`

tiempo = 24, entonces `24%12 → 0`, si el tiempo es 0, cambiar el tiempo a 12.

```
var dt = new Date();
var hours = dt.getHours() ; // da el valor en formato de 24 horas
var AmOrPm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = (hours % 12) || 12;
var minutes = dt.getMinutes() ;
var finalTime = "Time  - " + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + AmOrPm; 
finalTime // Tiempo final - 22:10
```

Fuente: [Cómo convertir el formato de 24 horas a 12 horas en Javascript.](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-convert-24-hours-format-to-12-hours-in-javascript-ca19dfd7419d)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares que son una muy poderosa herramienta. Te comparto el código de una función que hace la transformación que necesitas, usando expresiones regulares:

```
/*Javascript*/
function getFrom12to24Hours(stringTime){
  // Separamos la cadena de entrada del tiempo  en base al carácter (:)  en un array de dos elementos, según el formato hh:mm am/pm = [ 'hh', 'mm am/pm']
  let time = stringTime.split(':');
  // Validamos si se separó en dos partes 
  if (time.length != 2) {throw new Error('Invalid 12 hour format time')}
  // Extraemos la hora del primer elemento del array anterior
  let hours = Number(time[0]);
  // Verificamos si es una hora válida
  if(hours > 12 || hours < 0) {throw new Error('Invalid 12 hour format time')}
  // Separamos el segundo elemento del array anterior en base al carácter  de espacio ' ' para obtener los minutos sin el am/pm
  let minutes = Number(((time[1]).split(' '))[0]);
  // Validamos que los minutos sean correctos
  if(minutes > 59 || minutes < 0) {throw new Error('Invalid minutes')}
  // Usamos funciones encadenadas (se puede llamar una después de la siguiente con expresiones regulares.
  // .toLowerCase() coloca toda la cadena en minusculas
  // .replace(/\./g, '') reemmplaza los puntos  que puedan tener a.m./p.m. por '' es una forma de dejar lo esencial. Allí se usó la expresión regular /\./g, para buscar todos los . y reeplazarlos
  //.match(/\s(am|pm)$/) compara si la cadena quedó como queremos. para ello le pusimos la expresión regular /\s(am|pm)$/ que al tener $ verifica la cadena desde el final y compara si desde el final tiene am o pm. Si coincide con el patrón de la cadena, nos retorna un array con lo que necesitamos. Si no hay conincidencia con el patrón, retorna null
  let ampm = stringTime.toLowerCase().replace(/\./g, '').match(/\s(am|pm)$/);
  // Validamos que hayamos obtenido el array de coincidencia en base a la función match y la expresión regular usada
  if (ampm === null) {throw new Error('Invalid am/pm 12 hour format time')}
  // Validamos las horas y su relación con el am/pm (la hora 00 no puede ser pm sino am)
  if(hours === 0 && ampm[1] == 'pm') {throw new Error('Invalid 12 hour format time')}
  // Asignamos los minutos según el criterio de comparación adecuado usando operador ternario
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  //Asignamos la hora según el criterio de comparación adecuado usando operador ternario y concatenamos con los minutos y de una vez retornamos el resultado
  return ampm[1] == 'pm' ? (hours%12 + 12) + ':' + minutes :
    hours%12 < 10 ?  '0' + hours%12 + ':' + minutes : 
    hours%12 + ':' + minutes;  
}
           
// Probamos con:
console.log(getFrom12to24Hours('0:0 a.m'));
// 00:00
console.log(getFrom12to24Hours('11:5 p.m'));
// 23:05
console.log(getFrom12to24Hours('01:05 p.m'));
// 13:05
console.log(getFrom12to24Hours('4:09 a.m'));
// 04:09
```

Saludos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funcionan esas expresiones regulares. Puede que para ti sea claro, pero para los demás, no. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Asi de facil convertir de 24 a 12 formato y viceversa (solo habria que acondicionar los if y el pm/am)
Saludos!

var time;// esta variable es la que guarda el valor de la hora.
Para agregarle el valor, hay que ejecutar la sig. funcion:

```
getTime(){
        const date = new Date();
        let formatoMilitar = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
        const minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

    if(formatoMilitar>= 12){
       if(formatoMilitar=== 12){
       time = (formatoMilitar+": "+minutes+" PM")
       }else time = ((formatoMilitar-12)+": "+minutes+" PM")}
    if（formatoMilitar<=11）｛
     time = (formatoMilitar+": "+minutes+" AM")
     if(formatoMilitar=== 0 ){
      time - (12 +": "+minutes+" AM")
     }
    }
   
 return;
}
```